# get a state from another component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-leaflet

I have a Map component with a state.

```
const [userPickPos, setUserPickPos] = useState()
```

This state represents a marker's position on a map.

This Map component is returned in a page component. On this page I want to access this marker's position(the state of it) from the Map component.
How can I do that?

Map:

```
const Map = (userPos) => {

  const [userPickPos, setUserPickPos] = useState() 
  const MapEvents = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        const lat = e.latlng.lat;
        const lng = e.latlng.lng;

        setUserPickPos({lat: lat,lng: lng})
        console.log(userPickPos)
      },
    });
}


  const bounds = new LatLngBounds([81.505, -0.09], [50.773941, -84.12544])

    return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
            crossorigin=""/>

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
        </Head>

        <MapContainer 
        className='absolute h-screen w-[1500px] left-[520px] top-[56px] bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-[#738aaf]'
        center={[71.505, -40.09]} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={true} noWrap={true}>
        <ImageOverlay
          url="/allmaphres.png"
          bounds={bounds}
          opacity={1}
          zIndex={10}
        />
        {userPickPos && 
          <Marker position={userPickPos}>
            <Popup>
              Your Pick.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        }
         <MapEvents />
      </MapContainer>
    </>
    );

}
```

All (page):

```
const All = () => {
    . // I need to use the state here
    .
    .
    return (
    <Map />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit:

### State created in Parent Component and sent to Child Component

Map (Child):

```
const Map = ({userPickPos,setUserPickPos}) => {

  const MapEvents = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        const lat = e.latlng.lat;
        const lng = e.latlng.lng;

        setUserPickPos({lat: lat,lng: lng});
        console.log(userPickPos)
      },
    });
}
```

All page (Parent)

```
import React from 'react';
const All = () => {

  const [userPickPos, setUserPickPos] = useState()
  


 return <Map userPickPos={userPickPos} setUserPickPos={setUserPickPos} />
}

export default All;
```

---

### State created in Child Component and used in Parent Component

Map (Child):

```
const Map = ({handleCallBack}) => {

  const [userPickPos, setUserPickPos] = useState() 
  const MapEvents = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        const lat = e.latlng.lat;
        const lng = e.latlng.lng;
        setUserPickPos({lat: lat,lng: lng})
        props.handleCallBack(userPickPos)
        console.log(userPickPos)
      },
    });
}
.
.
.
```

All page (Parent)

```
const All = () => {
    
    const handleCallBack = (pos)=>{
        console.log(pos) 
    }

    return (
    <Map handleCallBack={handleCallBack}/>
    )
}
```

That way you could use the state in both components.

Comment: But I get the value from the map component and I need to use that in the page component.

Comment: Ok, you can see the edit now

Comment: Thank you this helped,but now I need the opposite. I have a state in the page component and I need to use it in the Map component. How can I do that?

Comment: You could just use my earlier answer. Create the state `userPickPos` in the Page component and send the `userPickPos,setUserPickPos` to your Map Component

Comment: And how do I access it? I have this:
`<Map getUserPos={getUserPos} solution={solution}/>`
and this:
`const Map = ({getUserPos}, {solution}) => {....}`
If I just log the solution it returns undefined whereas if I console.log it in the page it returns the actual value.

Comment: What do you mean log and console.log. Can you elaborate.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I don' know how to access the state in the Map component. I did `<Map getUserPos={getUserPos} solution={solution}/>` and `const Map = ({getUserPos}, {solution}) => {....}` but in the Map component `solution` returns undefined whereas in the page component it works fine, and it returns the numbers it is supposed to.

Comment: You can see the changed edit now

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`useCallBack` func, if you want to get the value from child to parent, as you can see the below code

```
const Map = ({handleCallback}) => {

  const [userPickPos, setUserPickPos] = useState() 
  const MapEvents = () => {
    useMapEvents({
      click(e) {
        const lat = e.latlng.lat;
        const lng = e.latlng.lng;

        setUserPickPos({lat: lat,lng: lng});
        handleCallback(userPickPos)
        console.log(userPickPos)
      },
    });
}
```

All page

```
import React from 'react';

const All = () => {


  const handleCallback = (data) => {
    // here you will get the value
    console.log(data)
    // your login
  };


 return <Map handleCallback={handleCallback} />
}

export default All;
```